# Datasource 'ds-mysql' is not available when using Service Activity Monitoring in Apache Karaf

Tags: mysql, jdbc, esb, apache-karaf, sam

I am a beginner in Apache Karaf, I deployed a Soap Webservice in Apache Karaf container (I use Talend Runtime), and I installed the SAM server with the following steps :

- I installed MySql Driver with : bundle:install mvn:mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.27
- I added the datasource with : feature:install tesb-datasource-mysql
- I launched the the sam server with : tesb:start-sam
- I configured the files org.talend.esb.sam.server.cfg as :

> > db.datasource=ds-mysql
> > db.dialect=mysqlDialect

- I configured the file org.talend.esb.datasource.mysql.cfg  as :

> > datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
> > datasource.username=myusername
> > datasource.password=mypassword
> > datasource.pool.maxActive=20
> > datasource.pool.maxIdle=5
> > datasource.pool.maxWait=30000

I restarted karaf and requested WebService, I am getting this error in the logs :
**org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not obtain last_insert_id(); nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Datasource 'ds-mysql' is not available**

The webservice works fine and my database is available but I can't get the SAM service to work, I spent many hours in internet without finding a clue.

Am I missing a step ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Not sure about Talend Runtime but usually with Apache Karaf one needs to install JDBC feature along with supported database driver feature for these to work. Also by default pax-jdbc-config that creates DataSource services from configurations expects files to have `org.ops4j.datasource` prefix i.e `org.ops4j.datasource-mydb.cfg` but this might be different in Talend.